# document.body returning iframe body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension that injects html to Linkedin. When I do `$(document.body).append($("<div>"));` from my Js file, it also appends for an Iframe component that's on the page.How ever when I type `$(document.body)` on the console it only returns main body.
How do I restrict it to only main body from my js file.?

My manifest file:

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,
    "name": "Hawk! Beta",
    "description": "Hawk",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
        "https://*.ngrok.io/"
    ],
    "icons": { 
        "16": "img/icon.png",
        "48": "img/icon.png",
        "128": "img/icon.png" 
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {                    
            "19": "img/icon.png",          
            "38": "img/icon.png"          
        }
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "js/lib/jquery.min.js", 
            "js/lib/asteroid/ddp.js",
            "js/lib/asteroid/q/q.js",
            "js/lib/asteroid/asteroid/dist/asteroid.chrome.js",
            "js/lib/asteroid/asteroid/dist/plugins/facebook-login.js",
            "js/lib/asteroid/asteroid/dist/plugins/google-login.js",
            "js/lib/asteroid/asteroid/dist/plugins/github-login.js",
            "js/lib/bootstrap.min.js",
            "js/background.js"
        ]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
             "https://www.linkedin.com/*"
          ],
          "all_frames" : true,
          "match_about_blank": true,
          "js": [
            "js/lib/jquery.min.js", 
            "js/lib/handlebars.js",
            "js/content_scripts/getPagesSource.js"
          ],
          "css":[
            "css/custom.css"
          ]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "img/*",
        "js/*",
        "js/lib/*",
        "css/custom.css",
        "html/*"
    ]
}
```

The code I used to inject html

```
function injectHtml(){
    console.log(document.body); //this returns 2 bodies
    $(document.body).append($("<div>", {
        "class": "myapp-container"
    }));
}
```

I only want to inject into main body and not into iframe body.

Comment: well you would need to select the iframe and than the content.

Comment: Sounds like your script is being injected into the iframe as well as the top level page. What are your manifest settings, did you restrict the locations it can be injected in?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your *manifest.json* file and/or whatever code you are using to inject your content script into the page. This information is needed to answer your question. Without this information, you have not provided a [mcve] which is required for debugging questions.  The point of a [mcve] is so we can duplicate the problem (i.e. so we have enough information to not have to *guess* at what the problem/solution is). Please leave a comment to me (include `@Makyen` in the comment) when you have added your *manifest.json* and how you are injecting your content script.

Comment: @Makyen ,I have added comment now. Please help.

Comment: @ShrihariIyer, Thanks for pinging me about the update to your question. Having the *manifest.json* file makes it an answerable question (as you have realized, the change that was needed was in that file). I have both retracted my close vote and reversed my down vote. I'm glad to see you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Patrick and wOxxOm , I edited the manifest file's content_scripts to look like below.

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
         "https://www.linkedin.com/*"
      ],
      "all_frames" : false, //this had to be changed 
      "match_about_blank": true,
      "js": [
        "js/lib/jquery.min.js", 
        "js/lib/handlebars.js",
        "js/content_scripts/getPagesSource.js"
      ],
      "css":[
        "css/custom.css"
      ]
    }
]
```

It now works fine. Thanks guys.

Edit:
all_frames:

> Controls whether the content script runs in all frames of the matching
>   page, or only the top frame.

For more we have,
[this link to know more](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Comment: Adding a bit of explanation as to why this change resulted in it working would make this a better answer.  In addition to an explanation, I would suggest also linking to ["content_scripts":"all_frames"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#all_frames).